# Apache Wicket: Communicate between independent pages of same application

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

On my wicket page I have a link that opens a second page in another tab/new window.

```
<a href="/MySecondPage" target="_blank">Click here for second window</a>
```

These windows are meant to be used in parallel (e.g. in a two-monitor-environment). But I don't want to spread out different menu entries over both screens, so I want all menu entries to stay on `MyFirstPage`, even if they should influence `MySecondPage` only.

My ultimate goal is to click a menu entry on `MyFirstPage` that results in displaying a new `Component` on `MySecondPage`. Is this even possible? How can I obtain a java-reference of `MySecondPage` inside `MyFirstPage` or establish some other sort of communication?
Everything I found while researching only applied to modal windows or Wicket 1.4, but `MySecondPage` is not modal.

Comment: Did you take a look at wicket-atmosphere? Since you need some kind of push behaviour, this seems like the way to do it.

Comment: My problem is not how to implement the push behavior for the communication. I can do that. My problem is how to identify the target where I should send the communication to. `MyFirstPage` does not know anything about `MySecondPage` (yet). How can I resolve this "yet" and obtain some sort of recipient information?

Comment: You'd need to change the link creating the second window to one creating an instance of the `MySecondPage` class using a constructur that accepts an additional object that acts as a link between those instances.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do that? I know how to open a page via link or javascript, but not via java code. That looks exactly like what I would need, so if you could post it as answer that would be great. For the communication afterwards I can use the event infrastructure Robert suggested below, I just need to know how I could pass a reference of `MyFirstPage` to `MySecondPage` (or vice versa).

Comment: nvm, I found the answer. Thanks, that was the final link I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe wicket's event bus is an option, see: http://code.google.com/p/wicket-guide/downloads/list - Chapter ***15.3 Wicket events infrastructure***

You could send the event in `MyFirstPage` , receive it in your `Session` or `Application` and there send it to `MySecondPage`. `Session` and `Application` implement `IEventSink`: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/event/IEventSink.html

Comment: Looks good, I could pass everything I need to the `onEvent`-method of `MySecondPage`. Still the `send`-method of `MyFirstPage` would need a reference of `MySecondPage` (parameter `sink`: an implementation of `IEventSink` that will be the receiver of the event) - any idea on how I can obtain that?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, maybe I just don't see the overall picture, but I still don't know how to obtain a reference to `MySecondPage` even from `Application` or `Session`. Basically all I know about `MySecondPage` is the URL (without any versioning id) and the fact that it has been opened. How can I get a `Page`-instance in any of these classes with just the URL or passing a `MySecondPage.class` somewhere? Or can I implement some `AjaxLink`-behavior that is able to obtain some sort of reference when the opening link is clicked?

Comment: Damn, it would have been a too nice solution. Thanks anyway, maybe I'll find some way to build up to this :)

Comment: Look at things like this: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/page/IPageManager.html - maybe youll find sth.

Comment: I went with your solution in the end, by implementing a `PageRegistry` where every page registers itself upon creation (tied to the session id of course). Now when `MyFirstPage` wants to send a message to `MySecondPage`, it can obtain the `IEventSink` of `MySecondPage` via this `PageRegistry` - and vice versa. This way every page is able to communicate with every other page whenever needed. The payload is flexible enough to pass everything around as I need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is WebSocket support in Wicket 6:
http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-native-websockets/

Basically you need to add `WebSocketBehavior` to the page to make it available for messages from the server.

On the other hand, you can send messages to the server via `Wicket.WebSocket.send("A message sent by the client");`

I have never tired it but it sounds very promising.

Comment: It does not solve my problem. WebSocket connections are page-specific, so a client with two opened pages has two connections, one to each page. So I'm still stuck with the problem how to get the event from `MyFirstPage` to `MySecondPage`. WebSockets would just help me to get the real update from the server to the client, but to do that the message that there has to be an update first has to reach `MySecondPage`, as only `MyFirstPage` knows about it...